# PHP with parallel port

Tags: php, parallel-processing

Does PHP has access to the parallel ? I'm trying to write data to the LPT1 port using PHP, but not having luck finding anything.

Comment: You want access to your **web server's** parallel port, right?

Comment: Could you give us more details about what you're trying to achieve?  There are a million different ways to skin a cat....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing to the parallel port is as simple as:

```
file_put_contents("/dev/lp0", "See that was easy.");
```

Your real problem however sounds to be:

> Does PHP has access to the parallel ?

Since PHP usually runs under Apache, the permissions for this device file are insufficient. On Debian systems you would add the `www-data` user to the `lp` group to make it work.